# Display timezone as part of long date+time in Windows/Outlook

Tags: windows, outlook, timezone

When working with teams across different time-zones and exchanging emails with them, I often find that it would really be helpful if I could put in my timezone when replying to emails.

For instance, when I use Microsoft Outlook to reply to an email, the email I am responding to gets included with the body of my email with the time+date in a format such as this

> From: Smith, John
>
> Sent: Friday, January 23, 2015 12:26 PM
>
> To: Me or my team
>
> Subject: TGIF

which I presume is based on the Windows settings for the long date & time which can be tweaked in Control Panel under Regional Settings.

Although I can set my timezone here, I dont find a way to include my timezone to become part of the long date or long time formats. I would like to see the end result like this on Outlook

> Sent: Friday, January 23, 2015 12:26 PM **PST**

Would anyone know how?

I am using Outlook 2007, and Windows 7, in case this matters.

---

My Googling powers dont seem to be working today. Perhaps because its Friday today. Well, at least in my timezone. ;)

Comment: if you downvote, please leave a comment why.

Comment: The question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) from the help center. You can ask this question on [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find such information in the PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS (DASL- http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F) property, for example:

> Date: Fri, 23 Jan 2015 06:47:04 **+1100**

Try using any low-level property viewer such as MFCMAPI or Outlook Spy for exploring property values.

The [PropertyAccessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868823(v=office.15).aspx) class can be used for accessing the value.

```
Sub DemoPropertyAccessorGetProperty()  
    Dim PropName, Header As String  
    Dim oMail As Object  
    Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor  
    'Get first item in the inbox  
    Set oMail = _ 
       Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1)  
    'PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS  
    PropName = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E"  
    'Obtain an instance of PropertyAccessor class  
    Set oPA = oMail.PropertyAccessor  
    'Call GetProperty  
    Header = oPA.GetProperty(PropName)  
    Debug.Print (Header)  
End Sub
```

Finally, I'd suggest asking non-programming questions on the http://www.superuser.com web site instead. The current forum/site is for developers and programming questions.

Comment: Ah, ok. I did consider using superuser.com but it seemed as if it was for Q&A for sysadmin/root users.

Thanks for replying. The `PropertyAccessor` that you pointed out is in the direction I was looking for, which would allow a dev to extend Outlook for such needs. So, I hope that makes it a programming question. :)